# Angular2 [routerLink] works, this.router.navigate seems to crash the app

Tags: angular, routes, routerlink

I'm having trouble with routes in an Angular2 application where using a button like this works fine:

```
<button [routerLink]="['/home/maincomponent']>Click</button>
```

But using the same route in a function fails - the page seems to load for a split second, then the application refreshes completely and lands me back at the main / root page, but there's no error on the console.

```
goToComponent() {
    this.router.navigate(['/home/maincomponent']); 
}
```

Also, navigating to the route just by entering the path in the browser loads the component fine without any error or redirect.

```
http://localhost:4000/#/home/component
```

Router Config:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home', 
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [{ 
      path: '', 
          redirectTo: 'dashboard',
          pathMatch: 'full'
        },
      { 
      path: 'dashboard', 
          component: DashboardComponent
        },
      {
      path: 'search', 
          component: SearchComponent
        },
      {
      path: 'maincomponent', 
          component: MainComponent
        },
      {
      path: '**', 
          component: DashboardComponent
      }]
  }
];
```

@NgModule Config:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
{
  useHash: true,
  preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
}),
```

Comment: can you put your routing configs please.

Comment: I've added the router configs to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong place for the problem. I'd bound the function call (click) to an

```
<a href="" (click)="goToComponent">LINK</a>
```

element, which fails.

Switching to

```
<span (click)="goToComponent">LINK</span>
```

element solves the problem.